# How to mount an old disk back to the RHEL VM without reboot?

Tags: redhat, vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, mount, scsi

**Background**

I have added a second hard disk (500GB) to this RHEL VM. And then format, created volume group (storerhel2) and logical volume (store) for it.
I then mounted it to a newly created directory (/newStore).
It showed as under sdb. Everything worked fine.

`lsblk -f`
sdb
└─sdb1                   LVM2_member       tcsmci-DJhs-19V8-UrKR-SOkI-hE1L-TuCqg3
└─storerhel2-store     xfs               eec69c87-8dd5-46c1-b402-1efe67d0489b    /newStore

`dmesg | grep sg | grep -i attached`
[   29.711244] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[   29.711471] sd 0:0:1:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[   29.711731] sr 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 5

I have then unmounted the disk from the VM, removed the hard disk on ESXi. After that, I re-added it back to the VM. But this time, it showed that the hard disk was under sdc instead of sdb. Also, the volume group was not recognized.

`lsblk -f`
sdc
└─sdc1                   LVM2_member       tcsmci-DJhs-19V8-UrKR-SOkI-hE1L-TuCqg3

`dmesg | grep sg | grep -i attached`
[   29.711244] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[   29.711471] sd 0:0:1:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[   29.711731] sr 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 5
[  675.053285] sd 0:0:1:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0

When I tried to mount it again to the original directory, it showed error.

`mount /dev/mapper/storerhel2-store /newStore`
mount: /dev/mapper/storerhel2-store: can't read superblock

However, when I rebooted it, the hard disk was successfully mounted again as it was written in fstab.

`cat /etc/fstab`
/dev/mapper/storerhel2-store /newStore               xfs        inode64,logbsize=256k,noatime,nobarrier 0 0

**Question**

How do I mount the hard disk again without rebooting the VM? I have tried identifying the scsi devices to rescan the disks (see the links below), same error. Has anyone ever come across the situation?

Please share your knowledge! Thank you!

**Reference**

https://kerneltalks.com/disk-management/how-to-rescan-disk-in-linux-after-extending-vmware-disk/

https://kerneltalks.com/howto/map-linux-disk-vmware-disk/

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/5/html/online_storage_reconfiguration_guide/rescan-scsi-bus

Comment: Please edit your question to include the block device you mounted, from /etc/fstab  or a mount command.  LVM LVs should be mounted by name label or UUID, but you mention lower level disks like sdc, which is confusing.  Yes, those drive letters can change.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have added in more content.

Comment: It looks to me that when I unmount the hard disk in the first place, it wasn't done "cleanly". Is there a way to unplug sdb cleanly so when I plug in the hard disk again (without rebooting) it would recognize it as sdb instead of sdc, just like how the system picks it up from fstab when rebooting?

Answer (score 2):

Linux LVM VGs should be deactivated and exported prior to doing work on their member PV disks. Unmounting a file system is not sufficient, there's a layer in between these.

For completeness, it is possible to migrate data from one PV to another while leaving the VG online. Storage migration things. Setting that aside for now, I'll assume this is the simpler case of off lining storage and detaching disks.

Reference LVM procedures under the use case of [moving a VG to another system](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9/html/configuring_and_managing_logical_volumes/managing-lvm-volume-groups_configuring-and-managing-logical-volumes#proc_moving-volume-group-to-another-system-managing-lvm-volume-groups). Which will include:

```
umount
vgchange -an
vgexport
```

Then once the disks are back bringing it online involves

```
vgimport
vgchange -ay
mount
```

Drive letters like sdb or sdc are not guaranteed to be the same. They are likely to change as paths to the (virtual) storage changes. Instead, reference unique identifiers under  /dev/disk/by-id/ such as lvm-pv-uuid  or wwn.

---

When making changes to disks, hosts aren't always aware of them immediately. That rescan-scsi-bus.sh script you cited covers all sorts of ways to poke Linux to look at its storage busses again without rebooting. Use as is, or read its source code to appreciate people's one liners for doing this task.

Some storage drivers are hypervisor aware, and do away with traditional SCSI interface. And so reflect disk changes (often resizes) immediately. vmw_pvscsi is VMware's Linux disk driver, any modern server distro should have it, but perhaps confirm that while you are working on the disks of this guest.

Comment: Thank you John. You really have shown me a new direction to look more into the volume groups. I will update the case once I have a better conclusion.

Comment: Consider accepting an answer that adequately responds to your question. You can create an answer to your own question if you found your own path. If you do edit your question with further detail, consider a comment to indicate it changed.